# Jmeter-How to capture the time from request is sent till it is updated in Database?

Tags: jmeter

I have an API https://xxxx-1-0-dev.us-e1.io/api/as3 which file send file from aws s3(based on filepath provided) to a target system. In between there are couple of other API involved while sending to target system.
API1 (Where we send file) ---> API2----> API3 which actually send file to Target system.
I need to measure the time taken from the time we hit the first API1 and till API3 which sends the file to target.
Once we hit API1, we get transactionID as response from API1, which will reach to API2 and Once API3 sends the file to target, It will update the status of  transactionID to payload submitted in DB.
Can i measure the time for each request from the time we hit the request till transaction is updated in DB.
My script is sending request to API1 and capturing tid as response that i am storing in Regular expression and querying DB to get the Received time and storing in regular expression.

But i need this to be logged in report. Can you help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the following:

1. Execute [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) to get the timestamp before you hit API 1 (or just after it, depending what you're going to measure) and save it into a JMeter Variable i.e. `${before}`
2. Execute __time() function again after the txn lands in the database (or get the timestamp from the database) and store it into a JMeter Variable i.e. `${after}`
3. Use [__longSum function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) to subtract `${before}` from `${after}` and store the result into the variable called i.e. `${delta}`

That should be the value you're looking for, see [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept

Going forward you can:

4. Declare this `delta` as a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) so it would be added to the .jtl results file
5. Plot the `delta` variable values in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)

Comment: Thank you, Now the after value from database is modified_date -2020-12-30 12:29:50.296, But before value is 122946, From db i need 122950 from 2020-12-30 12:29:50.296. Can you please help